# How to count method calls by instance

Tags: java, oop

I have following Code.

```
public interface Animal{

    void eat();
}

public class Lion implements Animal{

    @Override
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Lion can eat");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Animal lion = new Lion();
        lion.eat();
        lion.eat();
        lion.eat();
    }
}
```

as you can see I am calling `eat()` thrice. How can I calculate how many times it is called?

Note that,
you can not modify `eat()` method from class `Lion`

Comment: What *can* be changed? Can we change the first line in the `main` method? I'm not sure this is going to be a productive question, to be honest - nor do I think it's a good interview question.

Comment: Use a proxy class for `Lion` that counts how many times the method is called.

Comment: yes you can change everything except eat() from Lion.

Comment: if you wanna count just on lion so volatile static final int  counter , increment counter with syncronized method , it will work but if you want it on all subclasses so define it on interface ! hmm not editing eat okay use proxy  with counter

Comment: @MithatKonuk that's the common mistake. If you're going to use a `static` field, then it should be `AtomicInteger` at least.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes you are right thats true but if you learn basic java so first you just got volatile static int field right ! , after some level is up then tada ! atomic integer.we just suggest about  how is work  ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) with `Animal` interface and your `Lion` instance:

```
public class EatingDecorator implements Animal {
  private Animal target;
  private int counter;

  public EatingDecorator(Animal target) {
    this.target = target;
  }

  @Override
  public void eat() {
    target.eat();
    counter++;
  }

  public int getCounter() {
    return counter;
  }
}
```

and then apply it

```
Animal lion = new EatingDecorator(new Lion());
lion.eat();
lion.eat();
lion.eat();
System.out.println(((EatingDecorator) lion).getCounter()); // 3
```

Comment: To make the example a little clearer I'd change `EatingDecorator lion` to `Animal lion`. Otherwise one could think that implementing `Animal` might not be necessary.

Comment: @MithatKonuk Don't understand what you're saying/asking. Can you rephrase that?

Comment: The code is good but actually you don't use the decorator pattern but a wrapper. Decorator is transparent for clients as they can still use  the interface of the decorated object. It is not what you do here as you have to declare as type the decorator to use `getCounter()` or so perform downcasts that is not at all desirable in design patterns in general.

Comment: @davidxxx this is a clear example of decorator. Adapter is meant to use an interface (not a class) as another interface. Adapter is meant usually for classes that do not implement an interface, maybe classes from a different component/package that you cannot modify.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza I disagree. I referred to the wrapper, not the adapter sorry. If you cannot program by interface because the decorator added new public methods, it looks like more a wrapper than a decorator because decorators are mainly designed to decorate existing method in the decorated object. Here it does more.

Answer (score 5):

Use proxy can help, in many case we can't modify the code but we can make a proxy and do what you want.

code as follow:

```
public class Lion implements Animal {
    @Override
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Lion can eat");
    }
public static AtomicInteger counts = new AtomicInteger(0);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
        enhancer.setSuperclass(Lion.class);
        enhancer.setCallback((MethodInterceptor) (obj, method, args1, proxy) -> {
            counts.getAndIncrement();
            return proxy.invokeSuper(obj, args1);
        });
        Animal lion = (Lion) enhancer.create();
        lion.eat();
        lion.eat();
        lion.eat();

        System.out.println("method called " + counts.get() + " times");
    }
}
```

cglib dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could make a test unit with mockito - you run the the test and implement with following code:

Mockito.verify(mock,times(4)).send();

Comment: Proxy is a very important design pattern and method used very widely，take some time to learn，it will help you very much.